# React Native Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I have a React Native app I'm trying to deploy to an Android Studio's Android emulator, on Windows 10.

I run the app from an elevated Power Shell, using

```
react-native run-android
```

The Metro Bundler console opens, but the build fails with the following message:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':react-native-audio:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}.   Required by:
> >           project :react-native-audio

I have:

- React Native v0.59.10
- Node v10.16.3
- Android Studio v3.5
- Gradle:

  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"

  minSdkVersion = 16

  compileSdkVersion = 28

  targetSdkVersion = 28

  supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

I have tried changing to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` as per [the advice from github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2663), but that only resulted in a different error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

and make sure in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties the version is as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this pr, converting the quotes to double quotes:

> https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/pull/333/files

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}

// change to

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}"
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```